# where can we found wordpress WooCommerce fields are defined ? like (Order ID: %id% , Order Key: %order_key%)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to find where the wordpress WooCommerce  fields  are defined

based on this i want to define another fields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#25-85